# Recover files from WSL on secondary SSD

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

Before I swapped the SSD in my laptop for a new one I had Ubuntu running in WSL**1** on Win10 v1909. I have the old SSD in an enclosure and can access the files on it from my new Windows installation.

How can I get the files (mainly crontab file, home folder) from my WSL installation on the old SSD?

In the new installation under `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps` there are folders:

```
CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc
CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_2004.2020.424.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc
(and file ubuntu.exe)
```

Under `CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_2004.2020.424.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc` there is a `rootfs` folder with a Linux filesystem.

The old SSD is mounted on drive F:\ but under `F:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps` the folder `CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc` doesn't have a `rootfs` folder.

Comment: I mentioned I was running Win10 Version 1909 Which is OS Build 18363.836(`[Version 10.0.18363.836]`).

Comment: I know they switched WSL to hyper-v, before it was like the reverse of wine (compatibility layer not an emulator).

Comment: What happens if you type `//wsl$` in the Windows File Explorer as [explained here](https://www.howtogeek.com/426749/how-to-access-your-linux-wsl-files-in-windows-10/).

Comment: `\\wsl$\Ubuntu` shows the files for my Ubuntu installation on WSL on my new SSD. The files I seek are on my old SSD.

Comment: The screw to the M.2 SATA SSD that came in this was stuck to the mobo and M.2 chip, I had to pry it out to switch SSDs, not switching SSDs again since I could have easily broke the SSD chip and my laptop's motherboard meaning I would be out a laptop and new SSD.

Comment: One idea is to boot Windows in a virtual machine from the external SSD and copy the contents of the `\\wsl$\ubuntu folder to another USB drive or another folder in the same SSD.

Answer (score 0):

These instructions may or may not work for WSL1 to WSL2, but they at least work for WSL2 to WSL2 which I suspect at this point many people will be looking for instructions on:

```
wsl --import-in-place <distro name> <old windows root>\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Packages\<package for your distribution>\LocalState\ext4.vhdx
wsl --distribution <distro name>
```

In my case, I had my old drive mounted on `G:` and I was using Ubuntu from the Windows store so my full command was something like:

```
wsl --import-in-place OldUbuntu C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\ext4.vhdx
wsl --distribution OldUbuntu
```

This dropped me into a shell inside my old install and I was able to recover files from there.  It also added a folder to the `Linux` area in Windows Explorer so I could use a GUI to copy files around.